# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromWei' of undefined

Tags: web3js

My below code is working fine

```
Web3 = Require('web3');
const walletAddress = '0x8690F1feff62008A396B31c2C3f380bD0Ca6d8b8';
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(testnet));
var balance = web3.eth.getBalance(walletAddress); //Will give value in.
balance = web3.toDecimal(balance);
```

But when I run:

```
web3.utils.fromWei(balance,'ether')
```

It throws an error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromWei' of undefined"
```

I am using Web3 0.19.1 and node 10.15.1.

Answer (score 2):

With web3.js v0.x, use [`web3.fromWei`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromwei).

With web3.js v1.x, use [`web3.utils.fromWei`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#fromwei).

Comment: Hi,Thats working fine..Thnx for the quick reply